# Finite Field Extension and a Linear Transformation over it

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

We're given that, for $L,K$ fields such that $L/K$ is a finite extension.

Further, a linear transformation $T_a: L \to L $ is given by $T_a(x) = ax$

and are asked to show that the transformation

$Tr:L \to K$ ; $Tr(l) = trace(T_l(x))$

is a homomorphism defined from the additive group of $L$ to the additive group of $K$.

In my attempt, it was clear to me why the transformation is a homomorphism, as I've chosen a basis for the vector space $L_K$ (L over K) and found the the matrix of the transformation.

However I'm not sure of the reason why $(l+...+l)$ ($r$ times), for $r = [L:K]$, which I've reasoned to be the trace of the matrix $T_l$
must be in $K$.

Comment: Are you sure the map is what you wrote? Shouldn't it be left shift: $\;T_ax:=ax\;$ ?

Comment: ah yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove $\;T_a\;$ is in fact a linear operator from the linear space $\;L_K\;$ to itself, so if you write this transformation's matrix with respect to some $\;K- $ basis of $\;L\;$, the elements of this matrix are in $\;K\;$ and **thus** the map is actually $\;Tr: L_K\to K_K\;$ . i.e.: a linear functional.

If you knew already about the Galois group of a field extension the above can be done even shorter and faster.

Observe the matrix of $\;T_a\;$ **is not** $\;aI\;$ , since you have to write the action of $\;T_a\;$ on some basis using *scalars from* $\;K\;$ , and $\;a\in L\;$ .

Comment: Yes, for the $a \in L$ I've overlooked it and its essential for my question isn't it? thanks!